# Silverlight 3 - FindName returns null

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

This looks a bug to me.. Using Silverlight 3 and i have a user control defined in XAML and trying to access the object during runtime returns a null.

```
<Grid>
  <common:CommonGridEditPanel x:Name="scannerParameters" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Parameters}">
  <common:CommonGridEditPanel.Columns>
</Grid>
```

scannerParameter variable is assigned with null value, on further digging i noticed the below code in auto-generated section of the file.

this.scannerParameters = ((CommonGridEditPanel)(this.FindName("scannerParameters")));

Is this a known bug ?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile -- it's invalid XAML (the tags aren't closed).  Could you post the actual code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Known bug" in this area.  Like itowlson asks, it would help you showed us what you are actually doing.  Most likely what you are actually doing is where the bug is.